# Using @font-face in tumblr not working with RTL script

Tags: css, fonts, tumblr

I am trying to embed a font file to my tumblr blog using @font-face and Font Squirrel kit, but so far I had no luck. I also used base64 encoding for embedding the font, but neither in Safari nor Firefox I cannot get it to work.

Edit: Uploading files and using them to tumblr's static area works in Safari and for Latin script. The font I am trying to use includes characters from Old Turkic script, and I cannot get these to work. Any advice regarding the complex scripts would be appreciated.

My code is below:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'orkunregular';
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/gaobkbe/d1rn63eux/orkun-regular-webfont.eot');
    }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'orkunregular';
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff'),
         url('http://static.tumblr.com/gaobkbe/xtgn63ewo/orkun-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://static.tumblr.com/gaobkbe/nZcn63ey6/orkun-regular-webfont.svg#orkunregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

How to proceed from now on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done so far is, you defined the font-family. That will not make the browser use it.

Add this to your current custom css.

```
section.post {
    font-family: "orkunregular";
}
```

You need to apply that Font to the HTML-Elements you want to use it on. 
section.post would be only your own blogposts.

if you want everything to use that font, try:

```
* {
    font-family: "orkunregular" !important;
}
```

Please check the TOS of Tumblr if they allow that kind of customization, or atleast host those Fonts on a seperate webserver.

Comment: Okay, I already set the HTML elements, this time I changed the font file and it did work. So my problem is likely with the character encoding. The font orkunregular includes characters which are inside the Old Turkic Unicode code block. I can view these characters perfectly normal when I activate the font on my computer. But when I disable the font and try to see the font embedding if it is working or not, I only get boxes. Webpage is already using utf-8 encoding, any suggestions?

Comment: By the way, I can see the font rendered on the tab page in Safari, but not in window title bar and in the page itself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to store and serve the font files on tumblr itself. This is likely not permitted by Tumblr TOS.

Put the font files somewhere else and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've solved it. When generating the font kit, I chose the Unicode range of the Old Turkic script, then when used the new kit, it displayed without any problems.

Here's the blog page, http://bitigchi.tumblr.com/indiriler1

Thanks for all the answers.